# How to use generic template function to handle objects with different members?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have looked around a while for a solution to this, however, I might not know the exact definition or language syntax of what I am trying to accomplish, so I decided to post.

I have certain objects/structs like so:

```
struct A
{
  char myChar;
  bool hasArray = false;
};

template <uint8_t ARRAY_LEN>
struct AA : public A
{
  hasArray = true;
  uint8_t myArray[ARRAY_LEN];
};
```

I want to create a generic function that can take in both of these object types and to perform common work as well as specific work for the derived `struct AA`. Something like the following:

```
template <typename T>
void func(T (&m)) 
{
  if (T.hasArray)
  {
    // do some processing with m.myArray
    std::cout << sizeof(m.myArray) << std::endl;
    // ...
  }
  // common processing
  std::cout << "myChar: " << m.myChar << std::endl;
};
```

I want to be able to call the function like so:

```
A a;
AA aa;
func(a);   // compiler error, this would not work as no array member
func(aa);  // this works
```

Granted this is just an example that illustrates my intent, but it sums up what I would like to do. The actual code is a lot more complex and involved many more objects. I know I can overload, but I want to know if there is a way to do it with one generic function? Also note that I understand why the compiler complains with the sample code I would like to know if there is a workaround or some other c++ functionality that I am missing. I would not like to do any type casting...
- Using c++11 and GCC 4.8.5

Comment: Until C++17 you have no way of doing this within a single function. Constexpr if statements with a `has_myArray` trait could make this work.

Comment: @0x499602D2 This is C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overloading works just fine in your case if you don't want to modify your instances:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdint>

struct A
{
    char myChar;
};

template <uint8_t ARRAY_LEN>
struct AA : public A
{
    uint8_t myArray[ARRAY_LEN];
};

void func(const A &m)
{
    std::cout << "myChar: " << m.myChar << std::endl;
};

template <uint8_t AL>
void func(const AA<AL> &m) 
{
    std::cout << sizeof(m.myArray) << std::endl;
    func(static_cast<const A &>(m));
}

int main() {
    func(A{});
    func(AA<1>{});
}
```

If you still want to go with a template function and a bit of sfinae, I would probably use something like this instead:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdint>

struct A
{
    char myChar;
};

template <uint8_t ARRAY_LEN>
struct AA : public A
{
    uint8_t myArray[ARRAY_LEN];
};

void func(A &m)
{
    std::cout << "myChar: " << m.myChar << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
auto func(T &m) -> decltype(m.myArray, void())
{
    std::cout << sizeof(m.myArray) << std::endl;
    A &a = m;
    func(a);
}

int main() {
    AA<1> aa{};
    A a{};
    func(a);
    func(aa);
}
```

Note that in both cases you don't actually require the `hasArray` member data.

Answer (score 2):

This is a C++14 feature of reasonably large complexity.  C++17 introduced `if constexpr` to make this easier; but it is doable.

```
template<std::size_t I>
using index_t=std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>;
template<std::size_t I>
constexpr index_t<I> index{};

constexpr inline index_t<0> dispatch_index() { return {}; }
template<class B0, class...Bs,
  std::enable_if_t<B0::value, int> =0
>
constexpr index_t<0> dispatch_index( B0, Bs... ) { return {}; }
template<class B0, class...Bs,
  std::enable_if_t<!B0::value, int> =0
>
constexpr auto dispatch_index( B0, Bs... ) { 
  return index< 1 + dispatch_index( decltype(Bs){}...) >;
}

template<class...Bs>
auto dispatch( Bs... ) {
  using I = decltype(dispatch_index( decltype(Bs){}... ));
  return [](auto&&...args)->decltype(auto){
    return std::get<I::value>( std::make_tuple(decltype(args)(args)..., [](auto&&...){}) );
  };
}
```

`dispatch( some_test )` returns a lambda that takes `auto&&...`.  It in turn returns the first argument if `some_test` is of a true-like-type, and the second argument (or `[](auto&&...){}` if no second argument) if `some_test` is of a false-like-type.

We then write code to detect your `myArray`.

```
namespace details {
  template<template<class...>class Z, class=void, class...Ts>
  struct can_apply:std::false_type{};
  template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
  struct can_apply<Z, std::void_t<Z<Ts...>>, Ts...>:std::true_type{};
}
template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
using can_apply = typename details::can_apply<Z, void, Ts...>::type;

template<class T>
using myArray_type = decltype( std::declval<T>().myArray );

template<class T>
using has_myArray = can_apply< myArray_type, T >;
```

and `has_myArray<T>` is true-like if `T` has a member `.myArray`.

We hook these together

```
dispatch( has_myArray<T>{} )(
  [&](auto&& m) {
    // do some processing with m.myArray
    std::cout << sizeof(m.myArray) << std::endl;
    // ...
  }
)( m );
```

and now the lambda in the middle is run if and only if `m.myArray` is valid.

More complex tests that check for more than just existence can be written, but the above is usually sufficient.

In a non-C++11 compiler like MSVC 2015, replace

```
std::enable_if_t<B0::value, int> =0
```

and

```
std::enable_if_t<!B0::value, int> =0
```

with

```
class = std::enable_if_t<B0::value>
```

and

```
class = std::enable_if_t<!B0::value>, class=void
```

respectively.  Yes, these are uglier.  Go talk to MSVC compiler team.

If your compiler lacks C++14, you'll have to write your own `void_t` and either write your own `enable_if_t` or use the ugly longer version using `enable_if`.

In addition, the template variable `index` is illegal in C++11.  Replace `index<blah>` with `index_t<blah>{}`.

The lack of `auto&&` lambdas makes the above very painful; you may have to convert the lambda to an out-of-line function object.  However, auto lambdas where one of the first C++14 features people implemented, often before they finished C++11.

The above code is solid designed, but may contain typos.

Answer (score 1):

> there is a way to do it with one generic function?

I don't think so, because if you insert a `sizeof(m.myArray)` in this function, you can't call it with a type without a `myArray` member. Even if it is in a part of code that, run time, isn't executed, because the compiler need to compile it.

But, if I understand correctly, your `hasArray` say if your struct has a `myArray` member or not. So I suppose you can transform it in a `static constexpr` member, as follows

```
struct A
 {
   static constexpr bool hasArray { false };

   char myChar { 'z' };
 };

template <uint8_t ARRAY_LEN>
struct AA : public A
 {
   static constexpr bool hasArray { true };

   uint8_t myArray[ARRAY_LEN];
 };
```

Now, in `func()`, you can call a second function, `func2()`, to choose the two cases: `myArray` or not `myArray`. You can use SFINAE for this but (IMHO) is better tag dispatching, in this case. So you can transform your `hasArray` in a different type

```
template <typename T>
void func2 (T const & m, std::true_type const &)
 { std::cout << sizeof(m.myArray) << ", "; }

template <typename T>
void func2 (T const &, std::false_type const &)
 { }

template <typename T>
void func(T (&m)) 
 {
   func2(m, std::integral_constant<bool, T::hasArray>{});

   // common processing
   std::cout << "myChar: " << m.myChar << std::endl;
 }
```

Now you can call `func()` with both types

```
int main()
 {
   A       a;
   AA<12U> aa;

   func(a);  // print myChar: z
   func(aa); // print 12, myChar: z
 }
```

Remember to include `type_traits` and `iostream`.